# dmp file in Java?

Tags: java, c++, jvm, dmp

I know one can dump a .dmp file from a C++ project. This dmp file can be openned by the Visual Studio which is VERY useful because then you can navigate the call stack looking in variables values.

Does this mechanism exist for JVM too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`-XX:HeapDump` JVM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

With the following JVM options:

```
-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath="/tmp"
```

JVM will dump the content of heap to a file in specified directory. Note that this only happens when `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown since dump isn't really needed if JVM crashed due to a different reason.

You may also want to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html once

Comment: @DakashShah thanks, but I would like it to happen not only when OutofMemoryError is thrown. I would like my Java server to dump it's stack&heap when it gets any kind of Exception (I.e. NullPointerException)

Comment: Also, is it possible, using this method, to open the dump file through the Eclipse for navigating the call stack like Visual Studio dmp files?

Comment: @user1028741 I have not tried this, I suppose you will need to try it on your own and check it out

Answer (score 1):

### How to get a JVM dump?

1. You can use [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jmap.html) whenever you want to get a JVM dump.

   jmap -dump:format=b,file=/path/to/store/dumpfile jvmpid
2. You can add JVM option at startup to get a JVM dump when OOM.

   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
   -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/store/dumpfile

### How to analyze jvm dump file?

1. Use [Memory Analyzer (MAT)](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

[image: mat]

> The Eclipse Memory Analyzer is a fast and feature-rich Java heap analyzer that helps you find memory leaks and reduce memory consumption.

2.Use [IBM HeapAnalyzer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/alphaworks/tech/heapanalyzer)

[image]

> HeapAnalyzer allows the finding of a possible Java™ heap leak area through its heuristic search engine and analysis of the Java heap dump in Java applications.

Comment: +1 for very nice answer. I didn't marked as solved, because this is still only for tracing memory leaks, and not reveal the variables values in the stack when dumped. (I'm trying to debug other exception - not memory leaks).

Answer (score 0):

You can remote debug (e.g. [with Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/)) your Java application which allows you to view the stack and the variable contents.

Or you could take a Thread dump (e.g. with [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html)). But this does not include the variables.